# image doesn't display when I insert image in jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, jsx

I am trying to insert an image in a JSX file and I am getting this as an output -->

[image: Image of the output I am getting]

and that is my code, where I tried to place the image inside the same folder of the script and also in a different path and I am still getting the same image

```
    import React from "react";

import { Centered } from "meteor/empirica:core";

export default class InstructionStepOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
const { hasPrev, hasNext, onNext, onPrev, game } = this.props;

//const imagePath = "/my-experiment/img/table_image.png";
//const imagePath = "table_image.png";
const imagePath = "/meteor-empirica-core-master/my-experiment/client/intro/jpg.jpg";

return (
  <Centered>
    <div className="instructions">
      <h1> Instructions 1 </h1>

          <p><b> *** PLEASE NOTE THAT YOU WILL BE QUIZZED ABOUT THE GAME BEFORE IT STARTS *** </b></p>
          <p>Each game consists of a sequence of X rounds. Each round, you have a choice between two different actions (Choice 1 and Choice 2). You will have one minute to make your decision. After both you and your partner make a decision, you will each receive a certain number of points. This table shows how many points you and your partner will earn based on your choices:</p>

          <p>In each cell, the first number is how many points you will receive, and the second how many points your partner will receive. In other words:</p>
          <ul> 
          <li> If both you and your partner select Choice 1, you each earn 5 points. </li>
          <li> If you select Choice 1 and your partner selects Choice 2, you earn 1 point and your partner earns 7 points. </li>
          <li> If you select Choice 2 and your partner selects Choice 1, you earn 7 points and your partner earns 1 point. </li>
          <li> If both you and your partner select Choice 2, you each earn 3 points. </li>
          </ul> 

          <div className="task-image">
            <img src={imagePath}/>
          </div>

        <p>
        <button type="button" onClick={onPrev} disabled={!hasPrev}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={onNext} disabled={!hasNext}>
          Next
        </button>
         </p>
    </div>
  </Centered>
);
```

Comment: You should have a proper mapping of your asset folder in the webpack configuration. Otherwise after the compilation of the `JSX`. The path will be different.

Comment: Have you try to place the image in your public/assets folder and map it correctly?

Comment: @user573014, If an answer to this question has helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as **answered**. So that, it will help other users who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

The best way is to import an image file in `JSX` is to have a `index.js` file the image folder and export the files as export variables.

Example: Consider `assets` is the directory you hold the images, then the `index.js` will looks like the following.

```
export const myimage = require('./meteor-empirica-core-master/my-experiment/client/intro/jpg.jpg');
export const newimage = require('./meteor-empirica-core-master/my-experiment/client/intro/jpg.jpg');
.
.
.
Other images
```

And you import it in any component like the following

```
import { myimage, newimage } from "../assets";
```

I found it is a cleaner approach to load the images. I hope it will help in your case as well.

**Method 2**

You can directly import the image in `component`. But, when you have more images, component will look really bad.

```
const imagePath = require('./meteor-empirica-core-master/my-experiment/client/intro/jpg.jpg');
```

**Note:** You should follow your directory structure. In example, `../assets` is by considering your `component` is directly under `components` directory or any directory relative to the `assets`.